# How to get all Password Policies from Active Directory using python-3.11

Tags: active-directory, python-3.11, ldap3, password-policy

I'm using Windows server2019 as an AD-Server and python-3.11 in a domain joined machine to get the password policies of all the users and groups in Active Directory.

[image: Screenshot1]

I've tried multiple ways and codes but none stand out as I'm getting errors:

[image: Screenshot3]

which I even resolve but even after that getting NO Values as an output, attached is the code and output screenshot for better understanding:

[image: Screenshot2]

I'm not getting the point that when a policy (Minimum Password Length) is set and shown in GPO (password policy) so why it is not being fetched by the code.

If anyone can kindly help me out in this or guide me in this scenario.

I want to get the password policies of all users and groups in the AD from the domain joined machine using python. (I'm logged-in as a Domain Administrator in my domain joined machine.)